# Specify genre for iTunes Radio

Tags: itunes, itunes-radio

On older versions of iTunes Radio, I could type in free-form text for a genre for iTunes Radio (eg "Mongol").

Now, clicking on "Radio" just gives me a list of genres that Apple has chosen ("Alternative", "Classical Alternative", etc.). How can I search for a Radio Station of a genre I specify?

Answer (score 1):

The top-right corner of iTunes has a search box. Typing in "mongol" gives "Search for "mongol" in Apple Music". That gives "Showing Results for "mongol" in Apple Music".

Listed amongst that is "Top Results", "Albums", "Songs", "Artists" and "Stations". Stations lists radios such as "Mongol Radio".

Seems a rather roundabout approach, but at least it works.